# THEOS fatal error: <SpringBoard/Springboard.h> file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, tweak, springboard

When i try make my *tweak package*, I am returned with an error:

```
    Tweak.xm:1:9: fatal error: 'SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h' file not found
    #import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.cf890db2.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
    make: *** [SMSTrigger.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

My *tweak.xml* file contains:

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

%hook SpringBoard

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application {
    %orig;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" 
        message:@"Welcome to your iPhone Brandon!" 
        delegate:nil 
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" 
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

%end
```

My *makefile* contains:

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = SMSTrigger
SMSTrigger_FILES = Tweak.xm
SMSTrigger_FRAMEWORKS = UIKIT



include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from some research. For all who would like to know how to fix:

Use SpringBoard headers from rpetrich's repository from here https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders

Download these headers and put them in /var/theos/include. (If you're developing on your iDevice). Then type #import in your tweak.xm at the top and try to compile.

Comment: Looks like it's deprecated now.